# Android : Loading table data at run time

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

In my android application I need to load a `TableLayout` at runtime. I've already implemented a method to retrieve data from SQLite database which returns an `ArrayList`. What I want to do is how can I load these retrieved data in a `TableLayout` at run time? I need to write a separate method for it. In my xml file I've already defined a `TableLayout` like following. I need to load table data in this `TableLayout`. I would me much appreciated if anyone could be so kind enough to explain how can I do this?

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tblPersons"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: While this is certainly possible, please consider using a ListView for displaying lists of data. ListViews are made for this sort of thing.

Comment: `foreach elem in array {inflate tablerow; set tablerow fields with data from elem; tblPersons.addView(tablerow); }` but as Ken wrote ListView is better choice

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a bit of reading

[ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

[Custom ListView Adapter](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html)

Basic Idea:

1) You already have the layout xml, make it compatible for the listview [that's you dont need the table layout]

2) Make a ListView and write the custom adapter class for it

3) In which you have the option of Inflating your XML layout to the ListView as a ListViewItem